# How to Document via Graphic

Tags: java

Ran across this on the web, and it seems like a nice way to document a project.  Does anyone recognize if this is generated by a tool, and if so, what tool?

[image]

Comment: Looks like some sort of UML class diagram. If that's what it is, there are lots of tools for generating such diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how that's been generated but if your looking for a tool to create these programmaticaly then you could use [PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/index.html).

I hope that helps in some way.